# XCTests crash randomly when running on more than 2 simulators in parallel on iOS 13 simulators

Tags: xcodebuild, ios13, xcode11

When i try to run tests in parallel using `xcodebuild build-for-testing & xcodebuild test-without-building` via terminal (or in Jenkins) on more than 2 iOS 13 simulators, the tests start crashing randomly. The crashes start happening when the app does not get installed properly after running a few tests. Has anyone else been experiencing this issue and if there is a solution for this?

Comment: I've been battling the same thing - lots of random errors like `Failed to write updated test configuration` or `Only directories may be uploaded`. The only solution I've found so far is to stagger it with sleeps so the initial "buildy" part of each invocation isn't in parallel. Subshells seemed to help but I have no proof. Looking for something better.